# how to redefine the function "range" in Racket/Scheme?

Tags: scheme, range, racket

i'm trying redefine the function "range" in Racket.

```
(define (my-range a b)
  (if (> a b)
      null
      (cons a (my-range (+ 1 a) b))))

;; Test

(my-range 2 5)

;; -> (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 (cons 5 empty))))
```

Now I want to extend `my-range` as follows:

```
(define (my-range a b step) ...)
```

e.g. `(my-range 2 6 1)` --> `(list 2 3 4 5)`

The first number is `a` and each successive element is generated by adding `step` to the previous element. The sequence stops before an element that would be greater or equal to `b`. How can I do this?

Comment: just replace 1 in `(+ 1 a)` with your `step`.

Comment: (define (my-range a b step)
   (if (> a b) null (cons a (my-range (+ step a) b step)))) -->    (my-range 2 6 2)
(cons 2 (cons 4 (cons 6 empty))) but my output should be like this         (my-range 2 6 2) --> (cons 2 (cons 4 empty)) without b

Comment: thanx now i got it. I replaced the (> a b) into (>= a b).

Comment: the existing `range` supports providing a `step` amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments I guess you already found the solution. For completeness' sake, here it is:

```
(define (my-range a b step)
  (if (>= a b)
      null
      (cons a (my-range (+ step a) b step))))
```

In fact, this procedure is rather common and it can be expressed in several ways. As @dyoo has pointed, [`range`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/list..rkt%29._range%29%29) is a standard procedure:

```
(define (my-range a b step)
  (range a b step))
```

Also, in terms of [`build-list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._build-list%29%29), another standard Racket procedure:

```
(define (my-range a b step)
  (build-list (ceiling (/ (- b a) step))
              (lambda (x) (+ a (* step x)))))
```

Or using [streams](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-range%29%29):

```
(define (my-range a b step)
  (stream->list (in-range a b step)))
```

Comment: that works very nice...but it doesn't work in the beginner-mode.

Comment: now what to do to print an error message and abort the programm, if a > b

Comment: @Keyane create a helper procedure that checks for this before calling `my-range`

Answer (score 3):

To reiterate, [range](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/list..rkt%29._range%29%29) already exists in the Racket library; if you don't have to redefine it, just use the one in the standard library.

Comment: As I'm finding out right now, sometimes it's a good mental exercise to redefine standard procedures for yourself using more basic building blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I am just starting learning lisp-like languages (racket and sbcl). My answer is tail-recursive but only works when the start is greater than the end of the range, and the number of steps (divisions of the range) is specified instead of the step size. Although, it could be extended to work the other way around when the start is smaller than the end.

```lisp
(define (my-range-v1 start end steps)
  (let ([dx (/ (- end start) steps)])   ; step size
    (define (my-range-aux steps [acc end] [lst (list end)]) ; inclusive range
      (let ([x-dx (- acc dx)])          ; recursion from the end to the start
        (cond
          [(zero? steps) lst]
          [else (my-range-aux (sub1 steps) x-dx (cons x-dx lst))])))
    (my-range-aux steps)))
```

In `my-range-v1`, the variable `dx` holds for the step size. And this function starts at the end of the range instead of the beginning because each step is `cons`ed at the left of the current list at each function call.

I made another version which in turn receives the step size as argument (`step-size`) instead of the number of steps but it is not tail-recursive because of the way `cons` is used to construct lists (and because of my lack of experience with functional programming):

```lisp
(define (my-range-v2 start end step-size)
  (define (my-range-aux [acc start])
    (let ([next (+ acc step-size)])
      (cond
        [(>= next end) '()] ; base case
        [(cons next (my-range-aux next))]))) ; cons it all the way
  (my-range-aux))
```

Feel free to test them.

Also, you will find that the range is inclusive on both functions, i.e., the `start` and the `end` are included.